# Django allauth - Signing up a new user while already logged in

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to customize allauth's default SignUpView and SignUpForm to allow me to create other users while already logged in. The default behavior prevents me from doing this: in other words, I can only sign up for a new account if I'm *not* authenticated.

How do I override this behavior?

I presume I'll have to override the SignupView in `views.py` but I'm not sure what to look for... I played around with *RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin*, but to no avail.

**Forms.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class SubUserForm(SignupForm):
    USER_TYPES = [
        (2,'customer'),
        (3,'vendor'),
        (4,'supplier')
    ]
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    user_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=USER_TYPES))
```

**Views.py**

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

class SubUserSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'accounts/new_user_signup_form.html'
    form_class = SubUserForm
    view_name = 'sub_user_signup'

sub_user_signup = SubUserSignupView.as_view()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sub_user/',views.sub_user_signup,name='sub_user_signup'),
]
```

**To put in context**

My app allows for a 'parent' user to sign up multiple 'children' users (called 'subuser' in the code above) using allauth. In my case, an organization can create several customers, merchants, suppliers, etc. When a parent user creates a child user, a verification email is sent to the child user, who then activates his account and is prompted to enter a password. I use 2 signup forms; the default allauth signup (for parent accounts), and a customized signup form (for children accounts), which also extends from allauth.

Although the registration flow above works well, a parent user can only sign up new children users (trigger email verification) when logged out. I'm struggling to identify what I need to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I don't think django-allauth is designed to support a workflow like you describe.Also, this needs clarification: "I can only sign up new children users if I'm logged out." How does the "I" in this sentence relate to the parent users? And by "sign up new users" do you mean cause verification to be sent, or do you mean account activation?

In any case I think the path forward is going to be writing custom view code that wraps allauth functionality and makes it do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the feedback. I've rephrased and clarified some of my previous wording. Please see last paragraph above, which answers your questions. I haven't been able to find the functionality in allauth that prevents a logged-in user to sign up for a new account. I suspect it's RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, since it wraps the default SignupView in the source code. But I'm not sure how to go about overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the allauth directory, under app settings, set this to False

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS (=True)
The default behaviour is to redirect authenticated users to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL when they try accessing login/signup pages.

By changing this setting to False, logged in users will not be redirected when they access login/signup pages.

---

This also worked

Navigate to the allauth folder, under views find SignupView.

Deleting the redirectAuthenticatedUsermixin works

---

New issue is that you are logged in as the new user, fixing that currently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this article maybe useful:
https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2020-06/custom-signup-view-in-django-allauth/

The reason you can only sign up for a new account if you're not authenticated is because of this Allauth's mixin: RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin (as suggested by Anthony M).

So, you have to override this mixin and the allauth's signup view with your own code.

It is very important that you register the url before allauth urls.

Hope it helps.